# How to use WebView headless with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I want to run some javascript even when the activity is not visible. I can't create a WebView on the activity since the activity may be destroyed and the WebView garbage collected, so I thought about creating a headless WebView that isn't attached to an Activity.

I tried this:

```
webworker = new Xamarin.Forms.WebView();
Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource html = new Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource();
html.Html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n"+
 "<html><head><script type=\"text/javascript\">\r\n"+
 "function timer(){\r\n"+ 
 " window.setTimeout(function(){\r\n"+ 
 " console.log(\"webworker is alive\");\r\n"+ 
 " timer();\r\n"+ 
 "}, 1000);\r\n"+ 
 "}\r\n"+ 
 "timer();\r\n" +
 "</script>\r\n"+ 
 "</head></html>";
webworker.Source = html;
webworker.Eval("timer();");
```

But it doesn't execute the javascript. I'm not sure how to get it to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android , webview will block JS event in default . So you can enable it by using **Custom Renderer** .

> in your Android Project

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Webkit;
using Android.Widget;

using xxx;
using xxx.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.WebView), typeof(MyWebViewRenderer))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class MyWebViewRenderer:WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context):base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {

                Android.Webkit.WebView webview =(Android.Webkit.WebView) Control;
                WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;


                settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This led me to the right answer - instead of using Xamarin.Forms.WebView, use Android.Webkit.WebView. No need for the Custom Renderer but you do need to set webview.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true.